# Creating control for hashtag listing with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift

I a bit confused on this subject, and I'd like your help and thoughts on this. Basically I need to create filtering through my API by hashtags (for example cites). I could just put them like ordinary text in a `UITextField` that is separated with spaces and run API request with them, but that looks lame. Control I'd like to create is similar to this one (this is you something I created in PS).
[image: Control]

So, I need way for users to add tags to this box in very simple fashion like presented above, and create a way users can delete them by clicking a `x` button inside tag box.

In ideal situation I would like to be able to access tags from this control using `NSMutableArray` that is control property.

I'd like you to throw ideas and write how would you implement such control.